# SSIS mapping issue

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, ssis

How can I map a single SQL parameter like EMPName to a CSV file with two fields like EMPName and Name, using SSIS?

Comment: Instead of using table as source , create a query, use it as object Alias column name the way you wanted to map to

Answer (score 0):

Use a Derived Column transformation.